# TableViewCell label format different between two different NSStrings

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`. The cell just has a label on it for now for testing.

The issue that I have is that when I use the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HZEventCell *eventCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HZ_EVENT_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER];

    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.dataSource.eventStore];
    event.title = @"Document re-write meeting";
    eventCell.label.text = event.title;

    NSLog(@"Event: %@", event.title);

    return eventCell;
}
```

[image: Offset cell issue]

This causes my label to be offset when the app loads, hanging off the edge of the screen. If I pull the actual event data from my instance of the `EKEventStore` then the offset changes based on the event title. Some times the entire label is centered in the cell, other times the label is 50% off the left edge of the screen. If I print the contents of event.title via NSLog, there are no formatting issues that I can see.

When I use the following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HZEventCell *eventCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HZ_EVENT_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER];

    NSString *title = event.title; //self.data[indexPath.row];
    eventCell.label.text = title;

    return eventCell;
}
```

the label displays the text without any issues. It's not something that I am doing with the events in my data source, because the above code has me creating a new event, setting the title and assiging it to the cell's label, which still gives me an offset. It looks like cell.label.origin.x is equal to -25p. Anyone ever see this or know why this is happening? My sub-class of UITableViewCell has no code other than an outlet for the label in the header.

Note that I have this issue in iOS 6, I just happened to be doing this testing using the iOS 7 SDK when I took the screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps it's in Storyboard. Looks to be Auto Layout related.

Comment: I originally thought that too, but I created a fresh TableView template project and did nothing more than instance an EKEvent and still got the same result.